# Internet Explorer 11 is looping videos

Tags: internet-explorer, html5-video, internet-explorer-11

As the title suggests I have a problem with IE11. My videos are getting looped without me telling the browser to do this.
The strange thing is that the video is stopping like it should in all other browsers including Microsoft Edge (!).
I use a video tag to include the video in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround for this is the following snippet:

```
this.view.find('video').bind('ended', function() {
    self.view.find('video')[0].pause();
}
```

This adds an EventListener to the video which gets fired when the video ends pauses the video right after.